# Using a for-Loop to raise the row- index in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, rows

i want to copy a column of data from one worksheet to the next while transposing it. I want Excel to put a given value in "I3", then copy the data from "AA3 to AA72" in Table1, paste in "D4" in Table2 and delete the given value in "I3". Then the macro should put the given value in "I4" of Table1 and paste the data from "AA3 to AA72" into "D5" on Table2. And so on.

The code looks like this:

```
Sub FirstTry()
x = 1
y = 1

Value = Worksheet("Table1").Range("C1")

For s= 1 To 69

Worksheet("Table2").Cells(9,2 + x) = Value

Worksheet("Table2").Range("AA3:AA72").Copy

Worksheet("Table1").Cells(4,3 + y).x1PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Worksheet("Table2").Cells(9,2 + x) = 0

x = x+1
y = y+1

Next s

End Sub
```

The main problem is, that Excel doesn't raise the row-index. It puts a lot of values in "I3" and thats it.

Is there something wrong with my way to raise the index?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) use `Worksheet("Table1").Cells(4,3 + y).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`  2) don't use variables with special names like `Value`. Change it to, say, `myValue`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to raise the row number, dont make it a constant.

in your code, for example

```
Cells(4,3 + y)
```

should, maybe , look like:

```
Cells(3 + y, 4)
```

because row first , and column second, in cells(,).value